# Inline hyperlink in a comment

Tags: support, links

Can anyone tell me how do I paste a hyperlink into an coment? I always dislike long hyperlinks like this one:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_%28-0.1%29%5E%280.1%29+1.06%5E2*x%5E2*e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F1%29+dx

We can also see, that the above isn't fully reckognized (a bug or simply it all stops when the page wants to edit the link in italic) - only half of a hyperlink is infact a link.

Comment: `[Hello](www.com)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained at the bottom of the [formatting help page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) you use `[link text](url)`.

There is also [a more detailed help page just for comment formatting](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: How do I navigate to help center from the index screen. I can't find it...

Comment: I already found it. It is at the bottom of the page.